# Regroup array of objects by matching key/value pair

Tags: javascript

Is there a quick or recommended dynamic function to regroup an array of objects in javascript? For instance, if i wanted group by one key, and create of an array in the second key of all the second key values in the new object. Also lets presume theres no end to the amount of colors, so a new array position would have to be dynamic, we couldnt necessarily assume it. Example below:

From this

```
array = [
    {color:"red", number:23},
    {color:"blue", number:52},
    {color:"green", number:55},
    {color:"red", number:15},
    {color:"green", number:53},
    {color:"blue", number:23},
    {color:"red", number:25},
]
```

to this

```
array = [
    {color:"red", numbers:[23,15,25]},
    {color:"blue", numbers:[52,23]},
    {color:"green", numbers:[55,53]}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to group the values and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped values.

```js
let array = [    {color:"red", number:23},    {color:"blue", number:52},    {color:"green", number:55},    {color:"red", number:15},    {color:"green", number:53},    {color:"blue", number:23},    {color:"red", number:25}],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {color, number}) => {
      (a[color] || (a[color] = {color, numbers: []})).numbers.push(number);
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```